# ¿Se libera memoria asignando null?

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo

```
clase MiObjeto = new clase("Nombre1");

MiObjeto = null;
```

¿Liberé el espacio en memoria de Nombre1 al asignarle el valor null?

Answer (score 4):

Técnicamente si la estarías liberando. Cuando le asignas null a una variable, la estás dejando inaccesible. Luego en java existe un proceso en la maquina virtual llamado garbage collector que se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo y libera la memoria de los objetos inaccesibles.

Comment: ¿Y si no le paso null al objeto pero finaliza el método? ¿¿Es lo mismo que ponerle null??

Answer (score 1):

No, solo cambiaste la referencia de memoria(la dejaste de usar), el Garbage Collector de Java se encarga de borrar las posiciones de memoria que ya  no están siendo usadas.

En conclusión:

- No la borras instantáneamente, pero si le dices al garbage collector que la borre por ti, al ya no usarla (El garbage collector se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo).

Un poco más sobre el [Garbage Collector](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/garbage-collector/)

Answer (score 1):

Instantáneamente no. Lo que has hecho es quitar la referencia que existía al objeto recién creado. La memoria se liberará cuando el GC se ejecute, detecte que el objeto no tiene referencias y lo elimine.